# How to show data in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm going to to call some data by ajax() request as soon as clicking a button.

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react.There is an onClick function for each item. By clicking it an ajax() request will be called.The main problem is that I can not work on the result of ajax() request.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      DetailsRoom: {},
    };
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <div class="item">
          <div onClick={e => this.showDiv(e, item, i)}>Click</div>
          <div>{this.state.DetailsRoom[i]}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return <div>{renderInfo}</div>;
  }

  showDiv = (e, element, i) => {
    var mainprovider = element.id.provider;
    var optionId = element.families[0].optionId;
    var return_Room = (function() {
      var tmp = null;
      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        global: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        url: 'showAllRooms.bc',
        data: {data},
        success: response => {
          tmp = response;
        },
      });
      return tmp;
    })();
    return this.setState(prevState => ({
      DetailsRoom: {
        ...prevState.DetailsRoom,
        [i]: this.renderDetailsRoom(eval(return_Room), i),
      },
    }));
  };
  // The result of showDiv() :

  [{
    families: [{}, {}, {}, {}],
  }];

  renderDetailsRoom(DetailsRoom, i) {
    let lenfamilies = DetailsRoom.families.length;
    console.log(lenfamilies); /// TypeError: "DetailsRoom.families is undefined" ///
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'));
```

**Edit**

```
   fetch('/showAllRooms.bc', {
     method: 'POST',
      body: 'mainprovider='+JSON.stringify(mainprovider)+'&optionId='+optionId+''
   },)
   .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
    var Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
    this.setState(prevState => ({
    DetailsRoom: {
     ...prevState.DetailsRoom,
    [i]: this.renderDetailsRoom(eval(Maindata), i),
    },
    }))
  }).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

**Edit2**:
Response of success :
[{'families': [{'availablerooms': [{'info': {'room': '1/3 pax', 'cost': 0.0, 'availability': 'available', 'withbed': 0, 'withoutbed': 0, 'adults': 1, 'infant': 0, 'roomid': '0', 'double': ''}}], 'isRefundable': 'false', 'optionId': 'eydvZmZlcmlkJzogJzIkMiQ5MGVlNTZlNS1mYmE3LTQyYWYtYTE1My00MGViNzFhNTgzNmInLCAnc2VhcmNoaWQnOiAnJ30=', 'markups': {'totalprovider': 10256500.0, 'value': {}, 'totalmarkup': 0}, 'markupsuplier': {'totalmain': 10256500.0, 'value': {}, 'totalsuplier': 0}, 'totalPrice': 10256500.0, 'totalCom': 10256000.0, 'commissioncost': 0, 'services': '-', 'comdetails': {'type': 'number', 'val': 0}}, {'availablerooms': [{'info': {'room': '1/3 pax', 'cost': 0.0, 'availability': 'available', 'withbed': 0, 'withoutbed': 0, 'adults': 1, 'infant': 0, 'roomid': '0', 'double': ''}}], 'isRefundable': 'false', 'optionId': 'eydvZmZlcmlkJzogJzIkMiQ5OWM3OWYzOC00MzE4LTRjZDktOTkxNy05NGIwYmFmOGUzMmEnLCAnc2VhcmNoaWQnOiAnJ30=', 'markups': {'totalprovider': 15382600.0, 'value': {}, 'totalmarkup': 0}, 'markupsuplier': {'totalmain': 15382600.0, 'value': {}, 'totalsuplier': 0}, 'totalPrice': 15382600.0, 'totalCom': 15383000.0, 'commissioncost': 0, 'services': '-', 'comdetails': {'type': 'number', 'val': 0}}, {'availablerooms': [{'info': {'room': '1/3 pax', 'cost': 0.0, 'availability': 'available', 'withbed': 0, 'withoutbed': 0, 'adults': 1, 'infant': 0, 'roomid': '0', 'double': ''}}], 'isRefundable': 'false', 'optionId': 'eydvZmZlcmlkJzogJzIkMiRhODMyMzVhZi0wMmZlLTQ1MWEtYmFiYi1lNTM3M2EyOTY2NmUnLCAnc2VhcmNoaWQnOiAnJ30=', 'markups': {'totalprovider': 20513000.0, 'value': {}, 'totalmarkup': 0}, 'markupsuplier': {'totalmain': 20513000.0, 'value': {}, 'totalsuplier': 0}, 'totalPrice': 20513000.0, 'totalCom': 20513000.0, 'commissioncost': 0, 'services': '-', 'comdetails': {'type': 'number', 'val': 0}}]}]

Comment: from where you called the ajax in your code ?

Comment: And please dont use jquery with react. try the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead

Comment: if you log `return_Room` right before you call `setState`, what does it look like?

Comment: Hi @Dhaval Patel.Actually I didn't get what you mean.You mean is "showAllRooms.bc" my local file?

Comment: Hi @ Henry Woody. It looks like **///The result of showDiv()///**  in mycode.

Answer (score 0):

Do the setState after the ajax call's success method is called.
For example,

```
success: response => {
  this.setState({
    DetailsRoom: response
  })
}
```

Comment: I want to call data by `this.renderDetailsRoom(eval(return_Room),i) ` in `<div>{this.state.DetailsRoom[i]}</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [javascript fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make api call in `react`. You should `setState` in the **success** of ajax call. You can use following in `showDiv`:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    global: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    url: 'showAllRooms.bc',
    data: {data},
    success: response => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        DetailsRoom: {
         ...prevState.DetailsRoom,
        [i]: this.renderDetailsRoom(response.data, i),
      },
     }));
    },
  });
```

Comment: you are using arrow function so don't need to declare extra variable self

Comment: Yes, sorry as function expression was used in `return_Room`, so I think self is not needed. You can skip that

Comment: Thanks @Dhaval Patel, but there  is this error yet :TypeError: "DetailsRoom.families is undefined"

Comment: @bita I have updated answer. My assumption is that `response.data` will contain the required data. Also please share response you are getting from server.

Comment: Sorry but now the result of `console.log(lenfamilies)` is :TypeError: "DetailsRoom is undefined" and DetailsRoom  is undefined.

Comment: Please share response you re getting in success. Thanks

Comment: I try to use **fetch** request (you ca see it in my edited code) .But it has got the same error using **ajax** request.

Comment: You can see the response in Edit2

Comment: Try changing to `.then(response => response.json())`. Also why are you using `eval`?

Comment: changing to `.then(response => response.json())` , there is this error:SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 3 of the JSON data"

Comment: No need for JSON.parse after that.Please share code on codesandbox so that I can verify issue